# Minimum number of non-zero entry in each row and column such that a matrix has maximum rank

Tags: matrix-rank

Consider a square matrix of size N, such that each row and each column has exactly M non-zero positive elements.
A simple example with N=3 and M=2 would be

$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & A1 & A2 \\
 A3 & 0 & A4 \\
 A5 & A6 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Notice that this matrix has rank 3 (i.e. the maximum)
In general, for a given M, can one calculate the value of N that ensures that the corresponding matrix has the maximum rank? (i.e., rank = N)

Based on some tests that I did in a different context (too long to be reported here) I believe that the relation is 
$N = \frac{(2M-1)!}{M! (M-1)!}$ but I wonder if this can be proved rigorously.

Comment: Your formula doesn't work for the example you give : $N=3, M=2$

Comment: Pardon, there was a typo in the numerator, I fixed it now. Thanks!